# Authenticating Google Drive SDK

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Everything works when authenticating with Google Play service:

```
String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mActivity, mEmail, "oauth2:" + DriveScopes.Drive);
```

With the token I can now create my Drive instance and access Google Drive. But I realized that this is only supported for android 2.2 and up. I need to support android 2.1.

I have tried to use this code to get the token:

```
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
Bundle options = new Bundle();
am.getAuthToken (
        account,
        "oauth2:" + DriveScopes.Drive,
        options,
        this,
        new OnTokenAcquired(this),
        null);
```

When using this code I get a token but when using it to create my Drive instance I will not get access to Google Drive. When for example executing this code:

```
drive.files().list().setQ(trashed=false and title="'someTitle'").execute();
```

I will get this error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
{
    "code" : 401,
    "errors" : [ {
        "domain" : "global",
        "location" : "Authorization",
        "locationType" : "header",
        "message" : "Invalid Credentials",
        "reason" : "authError"
    } ],
    "message" : "Invalid Credentials"
}
```

This is how create my Drive instance:

```
    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
    Drive.Builder b = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null);
    b.setJsonHttpRequestInitializer(new JsonHttpRequestInitializer() {
        public void initialize(JsonHttpRequest request) throws IOException {
            DriveRequest driveRequest = (DriveRequest) request;
            driveRequest.setPrettyPrint(true);
            driveRequest.setKey(CLIENT_ID);
            driveRequest.setOauthToken(token);
            driveRequest.setEnableGZipContent(true);
        }
    });

    drive = b.build();
```

Comment: which library / jar are you using for JacksonFactory ? I am getting NoClassDefFound ERROR

Comment: @KKD I used [google plugin](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started) to add all jar files needed. This is the path to JacksonFactory according to Eclipse `com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I have solved it. The problem was actually that I used the wrong client id. When using Google Play service I used the client id for installed applications found in Google APIs Console. When using AccountManager this id was not working, instead I had to use the API key for Simple API Access.

**Edit**

Found out that this is not entirely correct. It seems like the client id to use is different for different devices.

Answer (score 0):

This seems correct, but the problem with AccountManager OAuth2 support is that depends on the platform version (Google Services libraries, etc.). It may work on some devices and may not work on others with a slightly different libraries. The only way to make sure it works consistently on 2.1 is to use a WebView to get the token. You can't really do anything if the AccountManager is broken or buggy on some device(s).

Comment: Do I need to use OAuth2 with Google Drive SDK or can I use another authentication which will work together with AccountManager?

Comment: I *thing* it only supports OAuth2, but do look it up in the reference, etc. In any case ClientLogin is deprecated and doesn't offer fined-grained control, and I don't think the AccountManager supports OAuth 1.0, so there are no other viable options really.

Comment: So I solved my problem. I have added an answer. Even if my problem is solved I get a bit worried about what you have said. Don't want problem for some users when the authentication is not working.

Comment: Cool. Accept your own answer then, so that the question is not left unanswered.

Comment: Will do but I have to wait another 5 hours before I can accept my own answer.